# Using Server.MapPath in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, server.mappath

I have the code

```
string xsltPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "\\" + TransformFileName
```

It returns

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websiteName\SERVICENAME\App_Data\FileName.xsl`

Why am I getting the path to the ServiceController, `SERVICENAME`?  I want the path to App_Data which is in

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\websiteName\App_Data\FileName.xsl`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to start from the virtual root:

```
string xsltPath = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data"), TransformFileName);
```

Additionally, it's better practice to use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to combine paths rather than concatenate strings. `Path.Combine` will make sure you won't end up in a situation with double-path separators.

**EDIT**:

> Can you define "absolute" and "relative" paths and how they compare to "physical" and "virtual" paths?

MSDN has a [good explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) on relative, physical, and virtual paths. Take a look there.

Comment: This works.  I was reading an article about the "virtual root", but I didn't follow it well.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath  Can you define "absolute" and "relative" paths and how they compare to "physical" and "virtual" paths?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey:  Absolute means the path from the root, such as "/someTopDirectory/someSubDirectory".  Relative means a path from where you are currently at, so if you are in "someSubDirectory" and want to get to "someTopDirectory", a relative path is ".." (go up one directory).  Physical paths are paths as the system sees them:  "C:\inetpub\myApp\someTopDirectory\someSubDirectory".  Virtual paths are as a web server application sees them: "/someTopDirectory/someSubDirectory".

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: To clarify more for your situation, MapPath converts a virtual path to a physical path.  In your parameter for the virtual path, you want to provide an absolute path instead of a relative one.  The marker to indicate the "root" for the absolute path in a web application is "~", so the absolute virtual root = "~/".

Answer (score 7):

The answers given so far are what you are looking for, but I think, in your particular case, what you actual need is this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString()
```

This will still return the file path to the App_Data directory if that directory name changes in future versions of MVC or ASP.NET.

Comment: I don't think that this is a particularly good idea. You are relying on an undocumented (officially) AppDomain parameter, it's an implementation detail. It is far more likely to change than `App_Data`.

Comment: It is documented, and standard, but it's for ADO.Net, not ASP.Net in particular. `DataDirectory` won't change but it may not always point to `App_Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this `(@"~/App_Data")`. `~/` represents the root directory.